# T9 Crossword Puzzle

Tags: crosswords

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #4: Cross-*non*-words](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/)</sub>

---

Anybody remember [T9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T9_(predictive_text))? Before fancy on-screen keyboards became commonplace, T9 was the state-of-the-art input method if you were limited to a 3x4 keypad. It was way better than [multi-tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-tap) and it even had some predictive powers!

[image: 3x4 keypad]

Well, this crossword puzzle is all about T9. The clues are given as T9 input and the crossword should be filled in the same way (that is: numbers only). Your final answer is a 14-letter word.

[image: t9 crossword]

**227677:**

1. 547843 2668246377
8. 7374687 27463 
13. 4323 26837464 
14. 84336 4263 
16. 66868246 5466
17. 7433 83277
19. 356937
21. 744 6328
22. 8973 63 72
26. 62746'7 83442537
28. 627837 63 23736669
29. 4363725 7877673 8344253
30. 237325 8973
32. 46773 76863
34. 968 263 63
35. 2676
37. 5874837 6666
39. 746437 __ 7433726
41. 253267 284534647
45. 5482436 8665
46. 96864 364
48. 372637 737 732663
49. 746753
51. 2583
53. 2583-47336 26567
55. 2784342425 468355443623
56. 376936 92837
58. 7746283
59. 566953343 4263
61. 77678 66 423
65. 362867
66. 54633 87
68. 26567
69. 7277 2929
71. 52846 82253
73. 2877428586 84823
74. 2256 3696
76. 36682255 2582
78. 63825 272387626
80. 737 4863733
83. 8973 63 78624
85. 52743 37848
87. 6228728466
88. 6455463837
89. 38767326 28773629
91. 94824 7765328
93. 67444625 42647837
94. 86225 67426
95. 5433 3973282629

**3696**:

1. 6678 545359
2. 6284 26678268
3. 7874366'7 8665
4. 76863 8368
5. 27526727
6. 4273 7435533 37848
7. 238837 2255 ____
8. 22233642 84853
9. 586467
10. 8973 63 287
11. 279 63 7246
12. 2374226 2686879
15. 58 5589 ____
18. 3477529 63 2646257
20. 2274825 2489
23. 3278 3679273
24. 436337
25. 7726474 9463
27. 46343337368 4378873
31. 8383726
33. 27426 2686879
36. 759 264625
38. 66473 94453 75337464
40. 836647 752937 24747 _____
42. 2667228 3472
43. 774373
44. 2229 7447
47. 2769
50. 52235
52. 2732 63 5263
54. 67426
57. 83764628466
60. 66253 427
62. 347639 66843
63. 2639 63 92837
64. 663 2455466 2487
66. 2624368 2646
67. 329 63 9335
70. 39732833
72. 6253 269
75. 6253 24453
77. 7726474 9463
79. 7877673
81. 3475 562539
82. 2274825 2489
84. 27754228466
86. 8648 63 7374782623
90. 68623
92. 4825426 74837

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

And hence the final word is

> **DIGITALISATION**! (34448254728466)

---

The answers to the across clues, or should I say '227677 25837':

> 1. 547843 2668246377 = LIQUID CONTAINERS (9) = **JERRYCANS** (537792278) - Thanks @Stiv!
> 8. 7374687 27463 = SERIOUS CRIME (6) = **FELONY** (335669)
> 13. 4323 26837464 = HEAD COVERING (3) = **HAT** (428)
> 14. 84336 4263 = VIDEO GAME (5) = **QUAKE** (78253)
> 16. 66868246 5466 = MOUNTAIN LION (4) = **PUMA** (7862)
> 17. 7433 83277 = SHED TEARS (3) = **CRY** (279)
> 19. 356937 = FLOWER (5) = **TULIP** (88547)
> 21. 744 6328 = PIG MEAT (3) = **HAM** (426)
> 22. 8973 63 72 =  TYPE OF PC (7) = **DESKTOP** (3375867)
> 26. 62746'7 83442537 = MARIO'S VEHICLES (5) = **KARTS** (52787)
> 28. 627837 63 23736669 = MASTER OF CEREMONEY (2) = **MC** (62)
> 29. 4363725 7877673 8344253 = GENERAL PURPOSE VEHICLE (4) = **JEEP** (5337)
> 30. 237325 8973 = CEREAL TYPE (3) = **OAT** (628)
> 32. 46773 76863 = HORSE SOUND (5) = **NEIGH** (63444)
> 34. 968 263 63 = YOU AND ME (2) = **WE** (93)
> 35. 2676 = BORN (3) = **NEE**  (633)
> 37. 5874837 6666 = JUPITER MOON (6) = **EUROPA** (387672)
> 39. 746437 __ 7433726 = SINGER __ SHEERAN (2) = **ED** (33)
> 41. 253267 284534647 = CLEANS BUILDINGS (7) = **JANITOR** (5264867)
> 45. 5482436 8665 = KITCHEN TOOL (4) = **OVEN** (6836)
> 46. 96864 364 = YOUNG DOG (3) = **PUP** (787)
> 48. 372637 737 732663 = FRAMES PER SECOND (3) = **FPS** (377)
> 49. 746753 = PIMPLE (3)  = **ZIT** (948)
> 51. 2583 = CLUE (4) = **HINT** (4468)
> 53. 2583-47336 26567 = BLUE-GREEN COLOR (4) = **TEAL** (8235)
> 55. 2784342425 468355443623 = ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE (2) = **AI** (24)
> 56. 376936 92837 = FROZEN WATER (3) = **ICE** (423)
> 58. 7746283 = PRIMATE (3) = **APE** (273)
> 59. 566953343 4263 = KNOWLEDGE GAME (4) = **QUIZ** (7849)
> 61. 77678 66 423 = SPORT ON ICE (7) =  **CURLING** (2875464)
> 65. 362867 = DOCTOR (2) = **DR** (37)
> 66. 54633 87 = LINED UP (6) = **QUEUED** (783833)
> 68. 26567 = COLOR (3) = **RED** (733)
> 69. 7277 2929 = PASS AWAY (3) = **DIE** (343)
> 71. 52846 82253 = LATIN TABLE (5) = **MENSA** (63672)
> 73. 2877428586 84823 = CURRICULUM VITAE (2) = **CV** (28)
> 74. 2256 3696 = CALM DOWN (4) = **HUSH** (4874)
> 76. 36682255 2582 = FOOTBALL CLUB (2) = **FC** (32)
> 78. 63825 272387626 = METAL CRAFTSMAN (5) = **SMITH** (76484)
> 80. 737 4863733 = PER HUNDRED (7) = **PERCENT** (7372368)
> 83. 8973 63 78624 = TYPE OF PUNCH (3) = **JAB** (522)
> 85. 52743 37848 = LARGE FRUIT (5) = **MELON** (63566)
> 87. 6228728466 = OCCUPATION (3) = **JOB** (562)
> 88. 6455463837 = MILLIMETER (2) = **MM** (66)
> 89. 38767326 28773629 = EUROPEAN CURRENCY (4) = **EURO** (3876)
> 91. 94824 7765328 = WITCH PROJECT (5) = **BLAIR** (25247)
> 93. 67444625 42647837 = ORIGINAL GANGSTER (2) = **OG** (64)
> 94. 86225 67426 = VOCAL ORGAN (6) = **LARYNX** (527969)
> 95. 5433 3973282629 = LIFE EXPECTANCY (9) = **LONGEVITY** (566438489)

And now the down clues (3696 25837):

> 1. 6678 545359 = MOST LIKELY (9)  = **LIKELIEST** (545354378)
> 2. 6284 26678268 = MATH CONSTANT (2) = **PI** (74)
> 3. 7874366'7 8665 = SURGEON'S TOOL (7) = **SCALPEL** (7225735)
> 4. 76863 8368 = ROUND TENT (4) = **YURT** (9878)
> 5. 27526727 = ARKANSAS (2) = **AR** (27)
> 6. 4273 7435533 37848 = HARD SHELLED FRUIT (3) = **NUT** (688)
> 7. 238837 2255 ____ = BETTER CALL ____ (4) = **SAUL** (7285)
> 8. 22233642 84853 = ACADEMIC TITLE (6) = **DEGREE** (334733)
> 9. 586467 = JUNIOR (2) = **JR** (57)
> 10. 8973 63 287 = TYPE OF CUP (3) = **MUG** (784)
> 11. 279 63 7246 = CRY OF PAIN (4) = **MOAN** (6626)
> 12. 2374226 2686879 = AFRICAN COUNTRY (6) = **ZAMBIA** (926242)
> 15. 58 5589 ____ = KU KLUX ____ (4) = **KLAN** (5526)
> 18. 3477529 63 2646257 = DISPLAY OF ANIMALS (3) = **ZOO** (966)
> 20. 2274825 2489 = CAPITAL CITY (5) = **QUITO** (78486)
> 23. 3278 3679273 = FAST FORWARD (2) = **FF** (33)
> 24. 436337 = GENDER (3) = **SEX** (739)
> 25. 7726474 9463 = SPANISH WINE = **SANGRIA** (7264742)
> 27. 46343337368 4378873 = INDIFFERENT GESTURE (5) = **SHRUG** (74784)
> 31. 8383726 = VETERAN (3) = **VET** (838)
> 33. 27426 2686879 = ASIAN COUNTRY (5) = **INDIA** (46342)
> 36. 759 264625 = SLY ANIMAL (3) = **FOX** (369)
> 38. 66473 94453 75337464 = NOISE WHILE SLEEPING (5) = **SNORE** (76673)
> 40. 836647 752937 24747 _____ = TENNIS PLAYER CHRIS _____ (5) = **EVERT** (38378)
> 42. 2667228 3472 = COMPACT DISC (2) = **CD** (23)
> 43. 774373 = SPHERE (3) = **ORB** (672)
> 44. 2229 7447 = BABY PIGS (7) = **PIGLETS** (7445387)
> 47. 2769 = CROW (5) = **RAVEN** (72836)
> 50. 52235 = LABEL (3) = **TAG** (824)
> 52. 2732 63 5263 = AREA OF LAND (9) = **TERRITORY** (837748679)
> 54. 67426 = ORGAN (5) = **LIVER** (54837)
> 57. 83764628466 = TERMINATION (3) = **END** (363)
> 60. 66253 427 = NOBLE GAS (5) = **XENON** (93666)
> 62. 347639 66843 = DISNEY MOVIE (2) = **UP** (87)
> 63. 2639 63 92837 = BODY OF WATER = **SEA** (732)
> 64. 663 2455466 2487 = ONE BILLION BITS (7) = **GIGABIT** (4442248)
> 66. 2624368 2646 = ANCIENT COIN (6) = **SHEKEL** (743535)
> 67. 329 63 9335 = DAY OF WEEK (6) = **FRIDAY** (374329)
> 70. 39732833 = EXPECTED (3) = **DUE** (383)
> 72. 6253 269 = MALE COW (4) = **BULL**  (2855)
> 75. 6253 24453 = MALE CHILD (3) = **SON** (766)
> 77. 7726474 9463 = SPANISH WINE (4) = **CAVA** (2282)
> 79. 7877673 = PURPOSE (4) = **GOAL** (4625)
> 81. 3475 562539 = DISK JOCKEY (2) = **DJ** (35)
> 82. 2274825 2489 = CAPITAL CITY (4) = **ROME** (7663)
> 84. 27754228466 = APPLICATION (3) = **APP** (277)
> 86. 8648 63 7374782623 = UNIT OF RESISTANCE (3) = **OHM** (646)
> 90. 68623 = OUNCE (2) = **OZ** (69)
> 92. 4825426 74837 = ITALIAN RIVER (2) = **PO** (76)

Comment: 1A = rot13(WREELPNAF)

Comment: @Stiv THANK YOU that ones been driving me absolutely insane

Comment: Well done for making it through - I imagine this took quite a while of intensive thought to work out! :)

Comment: rot13(vg fubhyq or tvtnovg abg zrtnolgr, fb ab glcb va gur chmmyr)

Comment: @user39583 ah that makes much more sense, thanks!

Comment: Well done, this is of course correct :) rot13(bayl 64 qbja vf fgvyy abg rknpgyl pbeerpg, gb or n 'ovg' avgcvpxl!)

Comment: @sarsaparilla done my bit to fix it ;)